# Keep columns of a data frame based on a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame, called `df`, which contains 4000 values. I have a list of 1000 column **numbers**, in a data frame called `list`, which is 1000 rows by 1 column. How can I keep the rows with the numbers in `list` in the data frame `df` and throw the rest out. I already tried using:

```
listv <- as.vector(list)
```

and then using

```
dfnew <- df[,listv]
```

but I get the error

```
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Comment: You mean like `df[list[, 1], ]` perhaps?

Comment: Could you give us an example of your code, what you have tried, what your output is, and what you wish it to be?

Comment: To the downvoter: Yes, it's a basic question, and it was not very well-worded question, but they did show what they tried and the error they got. Not sure that the down-vote was exactly warranted. To the OP, please share a reproducible example (as I did in my answer) in further questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up rows and columns subsetting. Here is a minimal example:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:21, ncol = 3))
df
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  8 15
# 2  2  9 16
# 3  3 10 17
# 4  4 11 18
# 5  5 12 19
# 6  6 13 20
# 7  7 14 21
list <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 4, 6))
list
#   V1
# 1  1
# 2  4
# 3  6
df[list[, 1], ]
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  8 15
# 4  4 11 18
# 6  6 13 20
df[unlist(list), ]
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  8 15
# 4  4 11 18
# 6  6 13 20
```

Note also that `as.vector(list)` doesn't create a vector, as you thought it would. You need `unlist` here (as I used in the last example).